# Order by with Cassandra No Sql Db

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

I'm starting to using Cassandra but I'm getting some problems on "ordering" or "selecting".

```
CREATE TABLE functions (
id_function int,
sort int,
id_subfunction int,
php_class varchar,
php_function varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (id_function, sort, id_subfunction)
);
```

This is my table.

If I execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM functions WHERE id_subfunction = 0 ORDER BY sort;
```

this is what I get.

```
Bad Request: ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

Where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY (id_function, sort, id_subfunction)
```

In Cassandra CQL the columns in a compound PRIMARY KEY are either *partitioning* keys or *clustering* keys.  In your case, `id_function` (the first key listed) is the partitioning key.  This is the key value that is hashed so that your data for that key can be evenly distributed on your cluster.

The remaining columns (`sort` and `id_subfunction`) are known as clustering columns, which determine the sort order of your data *within a partition*.  This essentially means that your data will only be sorted by your clustering key(s) when a partitioning key is first designated in your `WHERE` clause.

You have two options:

1) Query this table by `id_function` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM functions WHERE id_function= 0 ORDER BY sort;
```

This will technically work, although I'm guessing that it won't give you the results that you are looking for.

2) The better option, is to create a "query table."  This is a table designed to specifically handle your query by `id_subfunction`.  It only differs from the original `functions` table in that the PRIMARY KEY is defined with `id_subfunction` as the partitioning key:

```
CREATE TABLE functionsbysubfunction (
id_function int,
sort int,
id_subfunction int,
php_class varchar,
php_function varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (id_subfunction, sort, id_function)
);
```

This query table will allow this query to function as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM functionsbysubfunction WHERE id_subfunction = 0;
```

And you shouldn't need to indicate`ORDER BY`, unless you want to specify either ASCending or DESCending order.

Remember with Cassandra, it is important to design your data model according to how you want to query your data.  And that may not necessarily be the way that it originally makes sense to store it.